# InvalidElementStateException: Message: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys"

Tags: ios, appium, robotframework, mobile-safari, appium-ios

I'm trying to input URL on Safari on real iPhone device but got this error

`InvalidElementStateException: Message: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The on-screen keyboard must be present to send keys}`

This is my code

```
**** Settings ****
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections
Library    requests
Library    AppiumLibrary

**** Test Cases ****
Test_case_sample
    Open application    http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub    alias=Phone    platformName=iOS    platformVersion=13.3    deviceName=iPhone    bundleId=com.apple.mobilesafari
    ...    udid=**********************    nativeWebTap=true    automationName=XCUITest    noReset=false    wdaLocalPort=8145    useNewWDA=true
    AppiumLibrary.Input Text    xpath=//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="URL"]    https://www.google.com/
    Hide Keyboard    Go
```

1.I don't have any third party keyboard installed.

2.I don't want to use browserName=Safari because I want to verify the URL link.

3.Input problem only happen on Safari.

iPhone 7
iOS 13.3
Appium 1.17.1-1

Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a know issue with appium. Here is a thread talking about it: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10418

As for me, I fixed the issue by clicking on the element before sending to send keys to it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
AppiumLibrary.Input Text    xpath=//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="URL"]    https://www.google.com/
```

with following three lines:

```
AppiumLibrary.Click Element  xpath=//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name="Address"]
```

That seems to be the address element you can click. After you you click it, the element turns to text field. But at least as i tried it, the xpath does not get read quick enough, and the test fails unless we wait for it to become visible:

```
AppiumLibrary.Wait Until Element Is Visible  xpath=//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name="URL"]
```

And now input the text:

```
AppiumLibrary.Input Text    xpath=//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name="URL"]    https://www.google.com/
```

Should you have issues with the script failing to find the first element, then you might need a `Wait Until Element Is Visible` there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in my case by clicking on the nearby text label related to input element before setting the text value. I guess it is due to the input element's value can be added by scanning as well in this app.

[image: input element view]